# How can I get an array with the names of all defined categories?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to retrieve an array with category names.

It seems that tag names and category names are both stored in the same table (`wp_terms`), and to distinguish them you need to look in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table where the IDs from wp_terms are listed with options post_tag or category.

So I need to do some sort of relation query which, to be honest, is more than I can handle at this point. I did find that apparently there is some sort of a short cut to this. I haven't been able to find a good description of the function, but if you consider this: $wpdb->categories->cat_name` you may know what it's all about. I certainly don't.

How do I get an array with the names of all defined categories including nothing else?

Comment: Consider posting at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll be sure to do that in the future. I had no idea it existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_categories` for this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

This will fetch all categories

```
get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

I find the documentation to be quite good actually.

edit:

if you just need it for a static menu use the menu panel, add support for it in your theme first:

`add_theme_support( 'menus' );`

Comment: It would seem that you're right. Not that the documentation is good, because I certainly don't agree on that point, but the function does seem to do what it should, more or less. I am however still very much interested in how I do actually make a custom query to get the data, as I will need that knowledge later on.

Comment: depends what you are trying to get, wordpress has a lot of built in functions/classes that can accomplish what you need with less headache. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query can take care of most of your queries you need to do relating to pages/posts.

Comment: Writing custom queries is a bad idea - when Wordpress changes in the future, functions like get_categories will be automatically updated to continue working.  Your custom queries will not.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought using `get_categories();` would work for you. The documentation in the codex seems pretty straight forward. You can see exactly how `get_categories()` is used with `wp_list_categories()`

A lot of times when I can't find the right documentation for it, I just google something like "Worpdress Codex Get 'xxx'" and I can find what I need.

Let us know if `get_categories()` works for you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: I agree. The fault is mine and mine alone. As I've described in an edit in the original post, the problem is much more complicated than it looks. I simply thought that I could take one tiny step at the time. Obviously I was mistaken.

Comment: Well good luck to you. Let's hope the Codex proves helpful. It's really the only teaching tool that I use. I depend on it a lot. Maybe working with it more will make using the documentation more useful.